# What is the recommended way to backup a Magento website?

Tags: web-development, magento

What is the recommended way to backup a Magento website? Connect via FTP in terminal and run `mysqldump` command or use the backup function in the admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to generate the backups using FTP. Not unless you have shell access. Generating the backups from admin panel will be a good option if you are on a shared web host. It creates the backup & saves it under your root directory's var folder. Makes it easy for you to download via FTP.